# fabric ask for password for ssh user on Redhat8 even though I could ssh via terminal successfully(no issue on centos)

Tags: python, redhat, fabric

On terminal, I could ssh to the target server without password successfully.
The target server is redhat8.
But using fabric(I tried fabric==1.14.0 and fabric==2.6.0), both failed on waiting for password.

This is my test codes:

```
host = 'fake_host'
access_account = 'fake_user'
def test_connection():
    with settings(user=access_account, host_string=host):
        run('ls -la')

test_connection()
```

This is the result:

```
run: ls -la
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py:83: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
[fake_host] Login password for '<fake_user>':
```

There is no difference if I explicitly set the key file.

We have another server which OS is centOS7, with the same settings, we can ssh to the server without password successfully and can use the same fabric codes run the command successfully.

What is the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

We found the reason is because of high security settings on the target server.
Fix:
edit /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config -> add "ssh-rsa" to "-oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes".
Example: " -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=ssh-rsa"